# How do you deploy WireMock.Net as an Azure Web App

Tags: azure, .net-core, azure-web-app-service, wiremock

I am trying to deploy a ASP.NET 6 App which contains WireMock.NET as a hosted service. According to WireMock.NET's [wiki](https://github.com/WireMock-Net/WireMock.Net/wiki) this is possible and I'm basically using a copy of [this example](https://github.com/WireMock-Net/WireMock.Net/tree/master/examples/WireMock.Net.WebApplication.NET6) provided.

But when deployed as an Azure Web App, it returns a 404 rather than a response from WireMock.NET. What I should get back is:

[image]

The 404 makes sense to me because without specifying any URL/Port in the WireMock.NET config, WireMock.NET picks a random port. So requests coming in on Azure will be on port 80/443 but this won't be the port that WireMock.NET is listening on.

The image above was taken from [this GitHub issue/question](https://github.com/WireMock-Net/WireMock.Net/issues/564) where someone was having the exact same issue as me. They tried to configure WireMock.NET to listen on 80/443, but this prevents the app from starting up because the Azure Web App itself is using these ports.

As far as I'm aware you cannot configure Azure Web Apps to do port forwarding, i.e. to forward requests from port 80 to a port WireMock.Net is listening on.

Unfortunately (for me) the person with the issue/question managed to get it working, but it's not clear from the GitHub issue how exactly.

So the question is basically: how can I achieve this screenshot? Or, how do you deploy a hosted service (like `builder.Services.AddHostedService<WireMockApp>();`) that listens on the same port as the app itself?

Comment: Could you please try to add in your app settings as  `WEBSITES_PORT` and the value to `80` . (Azure> App service>your webapp> App settings).

Comment: Doesn't appear to make a difference. I believe that setting is only applicable for container apps?

Comment: @DavidMasters : please also read my comment on https://github.com/WireMock-Net/WireMock.Net/issues/564

Comment: Thanks @StefHeyenrath - I noticed that my web config wasn't the same, but now I'm getting: `The specified CGI application encountered an error and the server terminated the process.`. Tried to remove `forwardWindowsAuthToken` attribute as suggested in another SO post, but still doesn't work.

Comment: @DavidMasters, did you try the exact same example application and followed the steps to deploy it to Azure?